# new playlist created using ContentResolver doesnot show up in playlist

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

i have created a playlist using the follwing code

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME, "123456");

        //Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.getContentUri("external"), cv);
        Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cv);
        if (uri != null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),uri.toString(), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

each time i run the code i get the details as playlist created in content://media/internal/audio/playlists and then the id of the playlist is shown

now this activity is used to show playlists in the phone

```
public class playlist extends ListActivity {

    //define source of MediaStore.Images.Media, internal or external storage
    Uri sourceUri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    //Uri sourceUri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    SimpleCursorAdapter mySimpleCursorAdapter;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[] from = {MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME};
        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                this, 
                sourceUri, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME);

        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

        mySimpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                cursor, 
                from, 
                to, 
                CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

        setListAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);

        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(myOnItemClickListener);
        getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener (myOnItemLongClickListener);
        getListView().setLongClickable(true);
    }

    OnItemClickListener myOnItemClickListener
    = new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Cursor cursor = mySimpleCursorAdapter.getCursor();
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String _id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID));
            Uri selUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(sourceUri, _id);


            Intent i=new Intent(playlist.this,getsongfromplaylist.class);
            i.putExtra("id", _id);
            playlist.this.startActivity(i);
        }

    };

        OnItemLongClickListener myOnItemLongClickListener
        = new OnItemLongClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Cursor cursor = mySimpleCursorAdapter.getCursor();
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                String _id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID));
                Uri selUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(sourceUri, _id);

                Intent i=new Intent(playlist.this,popuplist.class);
                i.putExtra("id", _id);
                playlist.this.startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }

        };
```

in this activity all the playlists are shown which are  avaliable in the phone , but the new once created are not being shown

This also happens for the default music player which came pre installed for my phone

now i know the problem is

with

`Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cv);`

in the createplaylist code

and

`Uri sourceUri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;`

in the display playlist activity

if I change either of the`internal or external content uri` in respective codes that activity would crash

so my questions would

1) how can i create a playlist using `external content uri`

2) how can i display the playlist crated and all other playlists using both 
`external content uri` and `internal content uri`

Comment: FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER If set the adapter will register a content observer on the cursor and will call onContentChanged() when a notification comes in. Be careful when using this flag: you will need to unset the current Cursor from the adapter to avoid leaks due to its registered observers. **This flag is not needed when using a CursorAdapter with a CursorLoader**.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it is a code i am trying to learn, can you guide as to why i am not able to create a playlist on external content uri and how can i retrieve both internal and external content uri simultanoeulsy

Comment: `Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();` ? completely misuse of Loader's API ... **please read the docs!** ... `mySimpleCursorAdapter.getCursor();` inside `onItemClick`? ....